# How to correct collision between particles

Tags: physics, particles

In the use `particle system` how to avoid two `particles` intersect each other as in the following figure:

[image]

**Our settings for particles:**
`Physics = Newtonian, [checked] Size deflect,`
`Render: Object: dupli object : icosphere`

**Update**:
The original aim was to simulate separation of sands by some structures (combinations of tubes) due to their weights and the system configuration. So in our model, we used particle system to generate a continuous feed of sands into the system. Finally some sands are collected in some containers somewhere in the system.
The Figure shows a collector in which the intersection problem discovered. We also realised that not having self-collision between sand particles may bias the separation procedure as the particles do not collide each other, they were expected to do.

Comment: It seems that you need to script it some guy tried it before and documented his results here : http://pyroevil.com/molecular-script-docs/

Comment: What about using rigid body physics instead?

Comment: @stacker The script seems does not suit as it has string constraint between two specified particle. In our example, we generate particles with no link between any individuals.

Comment: @gandalf3 May you demonstrate how? As our trial to link particle system with rigid body physics was not successful. Regardless what the object is they intersect. If you mean not using particle system, then are you suggesting coding a script to generate randomly rigid bodies (writing a particle system, indeed)? Or you have some shortcut in hand?

Comment: @Developer If you don't need to create the objects dynamically (all the objects exist at the start of the animation), you can quickly create a bunch of rigid bodies with either a particle system or dupliverts or by duplicating once and pressing `Shift+R`, then using *Randomize transform*. Also see [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/3421/599)

Comment: @gandalf3 Thanks for the tip. Please see the update.

Comment: @Developer You could try *Fluid* particle physics (see [this post](http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5235/599))

Comment: We tried the example, but fluid particles are intersecting each other, they are not rigid though.

Answer (score 4):

There is a free addon for blender name "Molecular"
this addon is exactly what you need

http://pyroevil.com/category/scripts-addons/molecular-script/

http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?233643-Addon-Moleculars-physics