# Particles inside each other

Tags: particles

I have plane with sphere attached as object particle.

I have tried to set distribution jittered and random size of sphere.

What I noticed that there are smaller sphere particle inside bigger ones.

How to make sure that smaller particle spheres are not inside eeach other ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I prevent particle objects from intersecting each other and going though the floor?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46632/how-do-i-prevent-particle-objects-from-intersecting-each-other-and-going-though)

Comment: What if I use hair particle system with sphere object as particles? Then I can't set up collisions.

Comment: I know there are *extremely* to yours similiar questions on this forum, try the search again.