# Particles stick to side faces

Tags: physics

I have a plane "shooting" particles and I want those particles to stick to wherever they land and stay sticked. It does that on perfectly horizontal faces (the top of the cube) but if they land on a face from the sides they slowly slip off.

[image: sliding particles]

This is because of gravity but if I turn it off the particles will just fly off infinity in the direction they are "shoot".

The cube has these settings in the its Collision physics:
Stickiness: 10
Particle damping factor: 1
Particle Friction: 1

How can I make them stick to the side faces and stay there?

Using Blender 2.76

Comment: How about Die on Hit, and render "died" on the particle system?

Comment: That works good for non-moving objects but I have some that move and in those the dead particles won't move along with the object.

Comment: maybe give the cube a field attraction using surface?

Answer (score 10):

It can be done by using an addon called [Animation Nodes](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes).

[image]

The basic concept here is to get the location of each particle unit by the moment they die on hitting the collider. Then parent them to it immediately.

Here is a template setup:

[image] (2018-07-21 updated, compatible with AN2.0)

How to Use:

- Open the attached file;
- Download the addon from the link above, then install and enable it;
- Replace *Eimtter* and *Collider* object input on related nodes.
- Go to frame 1, play animation.

Comment: I know, it may involve a totally new tool. I'll see what I can do if additional guide needed.

Comment: Do you mind updating that answer for more recent versions, this is related to this [Question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111895/blender-undefined-socket-type-in-animation-node). Maybe more details such that it is useful without the the blend file.

Comment: @OmarAhmad Will do later asap.

Comment: @OmarAhmad Finally find some time to find what's going on. :)

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be your particle cache step. Setting it to one frame should at least lessen if not stop the sliding.

Essentially the eighth step in here:

[How can I simulate powder with a particle system?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/how-can-i-simulate-powder-with-a-particle-system)

Answer (score 0):

in the Scene tab you can turn off gravity, just untick the checkbox. I have some issues with particles bouncing off for high speed and grazing incidence angles but otherwise works fine.