# Blender - Undefined Socket Type in animation Node

Tags: particles, animation-nodes, collision

I am trying to learn the function "Particles Stick to side faces".

[Particles stick to side faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40376/particles-stick-to-side-faces)

However, I installed animation node in blender and find some source node in the node editor become **undefined socket type**. What is the meaning of this problem ? What can I do to make it work again ?

[image]

Comment: Animation nodes received a major upgrade this year, when version 2.0 was released. This also introduced an incompatibility, as some nodes were either rewritten or removed entirely. You can try to check out an older version of AN, or comment on the linked answer and ask for an update.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about version incompatibilities in Animation Nodes. Referenced answer should update the answer instead.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Is there some alternative methods to provide the function "Particles stick to side faces" in new animation nodes 2.0 ?

Comment: @FelixHo Yes there is. You should probably ask Leon to update his answer on the question you referenced. But new version has a relatively new particle system. So I will add a new answer to the question you referenced. Will notify you after answering.

Comment: @FelixHo Please see my upated file for AN2.0 in that answer.