# How to create realistic powder?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, particles

I want to model powder in a dish like in this picture.

[image]

I have tried to create the powder using the particle system by following [some suggestions in an earlier answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/5236/3710), but so far I had no success.

I can't control the overall shape of the powder, and the particles seem to pass through the dish even with collisions enabled.
[image]

Can someone please tell me how to create powder in Blender?

Comment: You'd be much better off sculpting a mesh with a noise texture for bump map I think then individual particles.

Comment: @poor yes I followed this question. I was referring to this when I said that I followed suggestions given in an earlier answer.

Comment: @hat Image or animation?

Comment: @poor just an image.

Comment: Take a look at the answer in http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44606/how-to-make-an-object-appear-to-be-buried-in-sand . If the shape of the powder pile is know, that geometry is created, then the particle system is used to put powder (rather than sand) on the surface.

Comment: Create a mesh in that shape, add a powery material to it and then add some particles on it for sparkle.

Answer (score 2):

You have two solutions :

1- Use the game engine to make powder fall and after save the last frame. You can model each particle of powder as a tiny cube for example, but it won't give you a result that is graphically appealing.

2- If you want to have a result that looks exactly like the image you posted you need to sculpt because of the special pattern that there is on the image.

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE, we appreciate all answers and your efforts, but we value more complete and full featured answers whenever possible, complete with more insight into the steps necessary for the user to be able to achieve the desired result.