# How can I make a baking soda model in blender?

Tags: modeling

I am trying to make a baking soda model but I cant figure out how to go about making it. Does anyone here know where I can find tutorials on how to do this. I searched all over Youtube but couldnt find any that involve making powder and exporting it with UVs.

Comment: you have some solutions for powder: https://blenderartists.org/t/how-to-model-a-pile-of-powder/550293/6  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/how-can-i-simulate-powder-with-a-particle-system/5236#5236   https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44606/how-to-make-an-object-appear-to-be-buried-in-sand   It would be interesting to know how you did it  ;)